# How to export data from Dollar Universe Workload Automation including embedded scripts

Tags: data-extraction

I am trying to export data from Dollar Universe Workload Automation to files using the following commands:

Session list file: `uxlst ses ses=* vses=* full`

Session details file: `uxshw ses ses=* lnk vses=*`

Task details file: `uxshw tsk upr=* mu=* ses=* vupr=000 nomodel partage`

UPR file: `uxshw upr upr=* vupr=* partage`

Rule file: `uxshw rul rul=*`

Resource file: `uxshw res res=*`

Calendar file: `uxshw cal exp mu=* since=2010 before=2014 nomodel`

Management unit details file: `uxshw mu mu=*`

The problem is that UPROC's that have an embedded script defined in them are exported without the content of the script.

How can one export data from Dollar Universe Workload Automation including embedded scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solves the issue:

1. set U_UPR_SCRIPT_NODISP=N
2. uxshw upr upr=* vupr=* partage SCRIPT

Screen shots from the documantation that explain the above:

[image]

And

[image]